# Teradata Kerberos SSO - Where to place the TeraJDBC.config and Java property file?

Tags: single-sign-on, teradata, kerberos

I am trying to connect to Teradata JDBC using Kerberos SSO.

I have read few documentation on how to connect to Teradata using Kerberos SSO. In most of the documentation I came to know we have to place the *TeraJDBC.config* file and the path of the *TeraJDBC.config* file in the *java property* .

But I could not find any concrete information on where to find the format of the TeraJDBC.config file.
Also can someone help me on finding the Java property to configure the path of the TeraJDBC.config file?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Teradata JDBC driver documentation](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html). Select "Using the Teradata JDBC Driver" section and then select the "Encryption, Authentication, and Authorization" topic. The actual text of the required config file is shown, along with instructions on how to supply the correct Java property and value.